# Display date 31-12-1969

Tags: php, database, date

I used date filed in my database. My Php page show:

```
31-12-1969
```

How to avoid this and shows the date blank or 0:0:0

Comment: `print $date == "31-12-1969" ? "0:0:0" : $date;`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the FAQ about posting questions. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: At the very least, figure out where `31-12-1969` comes from. Either allow `NULL` values for that field in your database, so they're really empty, and/or do `if (!$date)` in your PHP code to simply not print a date if it's empty.

Answer (score 2):

As you know, UNIX timestamp describe the number of seconds from the midnight of Jan1st, 1970. So, your 0:0:0 has no meaning, while the 31-12-1969 actually means <strike>zero, THE zero</strike> the data has a valid format but occupies no place in the timeline since UNIX epoch. So, it's blank if you evaluate it properly.

(Thanks to Leigh for the observation)

Comment: Surely to go before 1970 you'd actually need a negative timestamp, since 01/01/1970 00:00:00 is 0

Comment: @Leigh No, you just need to be in a timezone west of UTC.

Comment: Maybe Superman ran the world backwards. Again

Comment: There was me trying to make a joke, and then I ... `php -r 'var_dump(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", -1));'` - Wow, 1969 :D